# How to remove something in sheet 2 that is in sheet 1 and be left with unique values? PLEASE SEE ATTACHED

Tags: excel

I cannot figure out how to find unique rows in sheet 2. This is just a template list that I made to show what I mean. we can easily eyeball and see that on sheet 2, row 5 and row 8 are unique as their role has been added in sheet 2. I am dealing with a list of 200,000 clients and some might now even have a new row in sheet 2, so can someone please help me with how to identify new rows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qboxU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXseK.png)

Comment: I don't think your image matches your description. Row 10 is empty. Also, every row in your image is unique because there are no duplicates when you consider all five columns. I would consider re-writing your question and provide your definition of "unique". Also, define what you mean by "new rows".

Comment: sorry I messed up.. let me edit it

Comment: Hi @Isolated I have updated it, can you please check now?

Comment: So you want to know which rows on sheet 1 are on sheet 2?  Then you can filter those out and be left with rows that are not on Sheet 1?

Comment: yes pretty much. I want to know which row is added on sheet 2

Comment: Try this.   Stick this in Sheet2!F2 : `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,B2,Sheet1!C:C,C2,Sheet1!D:D,D2,Sheet1!E:E,E2)` and copy it doen so that all the rows of data on Sheet2 have this formula in column F.  Then filter for Sheet2 column F having a 0.

Comment: It works! thank you so much! @JerryJeremiah

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect which rows on Sheet2 are also on Sheet1 and which are not you can filter that result to show only the ones that don't appear on Sheet1.

Stick this in Sheet2!F2 :

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,B2,Sheet1!C:C,C2,Sheet1!D:D,D2,Sheet1!E:E,E2)
```

This is the count of times this row appears on Sheet1.

Copy it down so that all rows of data on Sheet2 have this formula in column F.

Then filter for Sheet2 column F having a count of 0.